Is it allowed to use cross validation when working with different datasets?
If I have two datasets with the same features but from different topics, and I want to train a model (e.g., SVM) on the first dataset and test it on the second dataset, how should I calculate performance (e.g., accuracy)? Can I use K-fold cross-validation during both the training and testing processes, or should I only use K-fold cross-validation when training and testing on the same dataset? I mean is it acceptable to use cross validation when train model in dataset and tested on another?

Welcome to Cross Validated! If you are determined to test your model on the second data set (might be a good idea, might not be), wouldn't the strategy be to build your model on the first data set as you always would while pretending the second data set does not exist until it is time to test?

@dave Thank you for your answer. If i already working to train model and test it on one dataset using K-fold cross validation, but I need to check the performance after applying the trained model on the second dataset how i can use K-fold cross validation in this situation? is this acceptable. my goal is to understand the decline in performance using same trained model

I'm not sure you do use K-fold cross validation in this case. You have decided that you have this second data set as the test data. The performance is then whatever it is. Do you see it differently? Is this, for instance, a homework exercise where the correct answer, according to the instructor, is that a K-fold cross validation is in play?

No its not a homework. I'm new in this field for that I'm working to understand which are  steps that I can follow in this situation and it is accepted. for example in some papers they mentioned they used K-flod CV when they worked with different datasets one for training and one for testing and some of them using whole first dataset as training and the whole second for testing. So, how they do it with cross validation.

Do they do it with cross validation? What is a reference to a paper where you think they use cross validation on a second data set? I'm not seeing how this is possible but would be interested in reading an explanation of why I am incorrect.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you please point to where in these articles they seem to be bringing the test set into the cross validation?

see  section B-Implementation Details at the end in link 1(appendix) and in link 2 see section 4.5

The Lin article sounds like cross-validation is used for tuning hyperparameters. I am still trying to figure out table 7 of the Wojdyga article, but it does not seem like they split the second data set into multiple pieces and then evaluated on each of those pieces separately. (Would it even be cross validation if they don't change the training data?)

I'm really don't know. And still confused about this. Do you think they used cross validation in the training and testing on same dataset. Then they tested the model on the whole second dataset ?

It’s not standard cross validation if they keep the training set the same, though some of the language in the linked articles does leave it unclear what exactly they did. It’s possible they chunked the other data set into five pieces and evaluated each of those five pieces independently, perhaps to get a sense of performance variability. I suspect that a bootstrap approach would give a better sense of this, however.

What do you mean by bootstrap approach? I'm really appreciate your answer thank you. Do you think if i need to evaluate the decline in performance what is the best practice for that?

Take 100 or 1000 (or whatever) bootstrap samples from the test data. Then evaluate the model on each one to get a sense of how much performance can vary.

@dave Thank you
